# Why is Clip so slow and how can I improve its performance?

Tags: performance-tuning, timing

The built-in function [`Clip`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Clip.html) is defined as a way to clip a value between a specified minimum and maximum. Another way to do this, is simply by utilizing `Min` and `Max` methods. e.g. `Clip[#,{1,3}]&` is basically equivalent to `#~ Min~ 3~ Max~ 1&`, but it seems `Clip` is way slower. Here are two tests:

```
AbsoluteTiming[# ~Min~3 ~Max~1 & /@ RandomReal[{0, 5}, 10^7];]
AbsoluteTiming[Clip[#, {1, 3}] & /@ RandomReal[{0, 5}, 10^7];]
```

The first one returns `{0.482735, Null}` and the second result is `{6.13182, Null}` which means `Clip` is about thirteen times slower. Now this might not seem a big issue since I doubt that anybody cares about the speed of such function, and it has an easy fix by the anyway. But I am just curious, why does this happen? In a parallel world where the humanity cannot access the `Min` and `Max` functions and they are stuck with `Clip`, how can they optimize it?

Comment: You only need to call `Clip` once: `AbsoluteTiming[Clip[RandomReal[{0, 5}, 10^7], {1, 3}]]`

Comment: Yes! `Clip` isn't slow. But `Map` is.